# Saying 'yes to all' using rm -i

Tags: rm

Say I wanted to make sure I'm removing the right files first, so I did something like:

```
rm -i *
```

just to make sure that I'm okay with the files that I am removing. So this will ask me for each file. After a few files, suppose I realize it's exactly what I wanted to remove. Instead of `CTRL+C`ing and just doing `rm *`, is there a way I can just say **Yes to all**?

This question comes more so from curiosity rather than functionality.

Comment: Strange question, but anyway, let's be creative in our answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

(Unless you find a way to flip the 'interactive' bit with a debugger.)

Comment: [citation needed] :-)

Comment: @Daniel: [`coreutils/src/remove.c:335`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/remove.c#n335) → `coreutils/lib/yesno.c:46` (generated) → [`rpmatch(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rpmatch): "returns 0 for a recognized negative response ("no"), 1  for  a  recognized positive response ("yes"), and -1 when the value of response is unrecognized"

Comment: Very nice find!

Comment: Also, you can just paste large number of y[line break] to terminal, which is not "Yes to all", but same thing happens.

Comment: haha true for the 'y[linebreak]' thing, i like it! :)

Comment: The correct answer is actually "yes". Pun intended. :-)

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a way I can just say Yes to all?

The answer is yes, using this code:

`$ yes "yes" | rm -vRI directory`

- v: show the list of files that have been removed
- R: remove directories and their contents recursively
- I: as per the recommendation above.

Answer (score 12):

Well, this doesn't really answer your question. But instead of using `rm -i`, consider aliasing `rm` to `rm -I`:

The man page states:

```
-I     prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing 
       recursively. Less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection 
       against most mistakes
```

in your `~/.bashrc`, put:

```
 alias rm='rm -I'
```

this is actually useful!

Comment: This isn't the accepted answer, but it is 100% correct (as opposed to the accepted answer which guesses it can't be done).   If for some reason your OS doesn't support `-I` then the "yes command" answer is also correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running in screen (a good idea in general), you can do:

```
ctrl-a : exec .! yes y
```

This would cause screen to run the 'yes' command with y being the output, and direct said output to the running program (rm -i).

Answer (score 3):

Just check first using `ls *.bla` and then `rm -f *.bla` maybe?

Use caution!

Comment: haha true this is a possibility

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by replacing the application file descriptors on the fly. You'll need an intermediate file though.

You can use gdb and a named pipe like this (assuming you are using more terminals, else you have to use screen or something else):

- create a named pipe with "mkfifo myYesYesPipe"
- start the interactive copy with rm -i and find its PID
- open gdb

Then type the following commands in gdb, replacing the PID

```
attach rmPID
call open("/path/to/myYesYesPipe",66,0666)
call dup2(3,0)
call close(3)
detach
quit
```

This replaces the keyboard with a named pipe for rm.

Now you have to fill the named pipe

- run yes > /path/to/myYesYesPipe

rm will read the pipe and overwrite everything.

Comment: @grawity. you inspired me to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the `rm` process in the background with `Ctrl+Z`.
2. Recall the last command (the `rm -i *` command)
3. Remove the `-i`
4. `Enter` to run the command
5. `fg %1`
6. `Ctrl+C`

Comment: `5s/fg/kill/; 6d`

Comment: How is this better than what the user explicitly mentioned he doesn't want to do?